# Update table from csv file

Tags: ssis

I want to update data content of table A with data content of CSV file,(table A and CSV file have the same column name).

Is merge join my best option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use staging tables:

1. Import csv file to [staging table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317162/what-is-a-staging-table) via flat file source
2. Create a Sql Task that updates tableA from staging table and truncates/deletes staging table in the same transaction

Comment: @BKChedlia - on the control flow tab connect your Data Flow task with an Execute SQL Task. In that Execute SQL Task place the `update tableA set field1=t.field1, .... from stagingTable t where tableA.id = t.id` and your delete or truncate in the same transaction

Comment: @BKChedlia How did it go?